# Groupby Sum returns the wrong sum value as it has been multiplied in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, pandas-groupby

Here's a sample code:

```
    import pandas as pd

data = {'Date': ['10/10/21', '10/10/21', '13/10/21', '11/10/21', '11/10/21', '11/10/21', '11/10/21', '11/10/21', '13/10/21', '13/10/21', '13/10/21', '10/10/21', '10/10/21'],
      'ID': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
      'TotalTimeSpentInMinutes': [19, 6, 14, 17, 51, 53, 66, 19, 14, 28, 44, 22, 41],
      'Vehicle': ['V3', 'V1', 'V3', 'V1','V1','V1','V1','V1','V1','V1','V1','V1','V1']
      }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

prices = {
    'V1': 9.99,
    'V2': 9.99,
    'V3': 14.00,
}

default_price = 9.99

df = df.sort_values('ID')

df['OrdersPD'] = df.groupby(['ID', 'Date', 'Vehicle'])['ID'].transform('count')

df['MinutesPD'] = df.groupby(['ID', 'Date', 'Vehicle'])['TotalTimeSpentInMinutes'].transform(sum)

df['HoursPD'] = df['MinutesPD'] / 60

df['Pay excl extra'] = df.apply(lambda x: prices[x.get('Vehicle', default_price)]*x['HoursPD'], axis=1).round(2)

extra = 1.20

df['Extra Pay'] = df.apply(lambda x: extra*x['OrdersPD'], axis=1)

df['Total_pay'] = df['Pay excl extra'] + df['Extra Pay'].round(2)

df['Total Pay PD'] = df.groupby(['ID'])['Total_pay'].transform(sum)
#Returns wrong sum

df['Total Courier Hours'] = df.groupby(['ID'])['HoursPD'].transform(sum)
#Returns wrong sum

df['ABS Final Pay'] = df.groupby(['ID'])['Total Pay PD'].transform(sum)
#Returns wrong sum

df.drop_duplicates((['ID','Date','Vehicle']), inplace=True)

print(df)
```

I'm trying to find the total sum per ID for 2 things: Hours and Pay.

Here's my code to find the total for hours and pay

**Hours:**

```
df['Total Courier Hours'] = df.groupby(['ID'])['HoursPD'].transform(sum)
#I've also tried with just .sum() but it returns an empty column
```

**Pay:**

```
df['ABS Final Pay'] = df.groupby(['ID'])['Total Pay PD'].transform(sum)
```

**Output Example for ID 1:** - ABS Final Pay

```
Date      ID   Vehicle  OrdersPD  HoursPD  PayExclExtra  ExtraPay
10/10/21   1      V1       1      0.1          1           1.20
10/10/21   1      V3       1      0.3166      4.43         1.20 
13/10/21   1      V3       1      0.2333      3.27         1.20


Total_pay  Total Pay PD   Total Courier Hours    ABS Final Pay  
   2.20        12.30               0.65                  36.90
   5.63        12.30               0.65                  36.90  
   4.47        12.30               0.65                  36.90
```

The 2 columns Total Courier Hours and ABS Final Pay are wrong because right now the code calculates the total by doing this:

```
ABS Final Pay = Total Pay PD * OrdersPD per count of ID 

Example: for 10/10/21 - it does 12.30 * 2 = 24.60
         for 13/10/21 - it does 12.30 * 1 = 12.30
```

ABS Final Pay returns `36.90` when it should be `12.30 (7.83 + 4.47 from the 2 days)`

**Total Pay PD** for ID 1 is also wrong as it should show the sum of pay per date, example of expected output:

```
Date      ID   Vehicle OrdersPD  Total PD
10/10/21   1     V1      1         7.83 
10/10/21   1     V3      1         7.83 
13/10/21   1     V1      1         4.47
```

Total Courier Hours seems to be fine for ID 1 when it's split into 3 rows with 1 order per row but when it has more than 1 order, it calculates it wrong as it multiplies it.

**Example for ID 2** - Total Courier Hours

It calculates it doing this sum:

```
Total Courier Hours = HoursPD * OrdersPD per count of ID 

Example: 11/10/21 - ID 2 had 5 orders, 2.85 * 5 = 14.25
         13/10/21 - 3 orders, 2.01 * 3 = 6.03
         10/10/21 - 2 orders, 1.05 * 2 = 2.1
```

Total Courier Hours returns `22.38` when it should be `5.91 (2.85 + 2.01 + 1.05 from the 3 days)`

Sorry for the long post, I hope this makes sense and thanks in advance.

Comment: Quick note `transform('sum')` is a lot faster than `transform(sum)`

Comment: `df['Total Pay PD'] = df.groupby(['ID', 'Date'])['Total_pay'].transform(sum)`.  "ABS Final Pay" is wrong because "Total Pay PD" is wrong.

Comment: I can't get through your logics yet. but looks like you `transform('sum')` too many times. E.g. ID2 has 5 rows, `HoursPD` is duplicate 5 times, each is already total hours . Then you do `total_pay` that is sum of those 5 rows, sounds just wrong to me.

Comment: @QuangHoang Sorry :D I'm pretty new to Pandas and using Python so this is probably a super long winded way of writing the code when it could be massively simplified. I have to use `transform(sum)` otherwise the column return is empty with no values to show.

Comment: @QuangHoang ID2 Should have 5 rows for order dates on 11/10/21 but it won't be printed because I've used `drop_duplicate` to make it easier to read.

Comment: For one thing, you don't need `MinutesPD` and `HoursPD`. Try to calculate the `Total_Pay` by rows, then finally group by `ID` and sum. You should definitely add your expected output. I mean the output that you are **really** care about, not the intermediate values.

Comment: @QuangHoang I added a MinutedPD because I wasn't sure how else to show the Hours for each date, vehicle and ID. Originally it was just `df['HoursPD'] = df['TotalTimeSpentInMinutes'] / 60` but this wouldn't give me a breakdown per vehicle if that makes sense?

Comment: don't duplicate your own questions [df.groupby(....).sum() isn't returning the expected output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69853495/df-groupby-sum-isnt-returning-the-expected-output)

Comment: @diggusbickus Sorry I had updated the code and wanted to delete the other post but I didn't want to get banned for deleting an answered post.

Comment: you edit your question then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The drop_duplicates line may have been the issue. Once I removed the code:

`df.drop_duplicates((['ID','Date','Vehicle']), inplace=True)`

I was able to calculate the totals more accurately line by line instead of having to do calculations to the columns within the code.

To separate it neatly, I printed the columns by groupby's in a different excel sheet.

Example:

```
per_courier = (
    df.groupby(['ID'])['Total Pay']
    .agg(sum)
)
```